# Postfix, Dovecot mail server can send mails but not receive

Tags: server, dns, postfix, mail, dovecot

I'm new to Linux servers and just got myself a VPS from Ovh. Also got a domain though ovh.

I have tried to use this [tutorial](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/) to set it up. And I guess that somewhere I must have messed up. The issue is that I can't receive emails. I can send them fine, and when I try to send emails to my domain it doesn't give delivery error, it just doesn't show up.

This leads me to believe that the email goes though, but somehow in my configuration it gets sent to a wrong location on the server.

`Postfix Main.cf`:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = $mydomain

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = stahp.ovh
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = stahp.ovh, vps141712.ovh.net, localhost.ovh.net, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

`10-mail.conf`  - Dovecot config

```
##
## Mailbox locations and namespaces
##

# Location for users' mailboxes. The default is empty, which means that Dovecot
# tries to find the mailboxes automatically. This won't work if the user
# doesn't yet have any mail, so you should explicitly tell Dovecot the full
# location.
#
# If you're using mbox, giving a path to the INBOX file (eg. /var/mail/%u)
# isn't enough. You'll also need to tell Dovecot where the other mailboxes are
# kept. This is called the "root mail directory", and it must be the first
# path given in the mail_location setting.
#
# There are a few special variables you can use, eg.:
#
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if there's no domain
#   %h - home directory
#
# See doc/wiki/Variables.txt for full list. Some examples:
#
#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
#
# <doc/wiki/MailLocation.txt>
#
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

# If you need to set multiple mailbox locations or want to change default
# namespace settings, you can do it by defining namespace sections.
#
# You can have private, shared and public namespaces. Private namespaces
# are for user's personal mails. Shared namespaces are for accessing other
# users' mailboxes that have been shared. Public namespaces are for shared
# mailboxes that are managed by sysadmin. If you create any shared or public
# namespaces you'll typically want to enable ACL plugin also, otherwise all
# users can access all the shared mailboxes, assuming they have permissions
# on filesystem level to do so.
namespace inbox {
  # Namespace type: private, shared or public
  #type = private

  # Hierarchy separator to use. You should use the same separator for all
  # namespaces or some clients get confused. '/' is usually a good one.
  # The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format.
  #separator =

  # Prefix required to access this namespace. This needs to be different for
  # all namespaces. For example "Public/".
  #prefix =

  # Physical location of the mailbox. This is in same format as
 # mail_location, which is also the default for it.
  #location =

  # There can be only one INBOX, and this setting defines which namespace
  # has it.
  inbox = yes

  # If namespace is hidden, it's not advertised to clients via NAMESPACE
  # extension. You'll most likely also want to set list=no. This is mostly
  # useful when converting from another server with different namespaces which
  # you want to deprecate but still keep working. For example you can create
  # hidden namespaces with prefixes "~/mail/", "~%u/mail/" and "mail/".
  #hidden = no

  # Show the mailboxes under this namespace with LIST command. This makes the
  # namespace visible for clients that don't support NAMESPACE extension.
  # "children" value lists child mailboxes, but hides the namespace prefix.
  #list = yes

  # Namespace handles its own subscriptions. If set to "no", the parent
  # namespace handles them (empty prefix should always have this as "yes")
  #subscriptions = yes
}

# Example shared namespace configuration
#namespace {
  #type = shared
  #separator = /

  # Mailboxes are visible under "shared/user@domain/"
  # %%n, %%d and %%u are expanded to the destination user.
  #prefix = shared/%%u/

  # Mail location for other users' mailboxes. Note that %variables and ~/
  # expands to the logged in user's data. %%n, %%d, %%u and %%h expand to the
  # destination user's data.
  #location = maildir:%%h/Maildir:INDEX=~/Maildir/shared/%%u
  # Use the default namespace for saving subscriptions.
  #subscriptions = no

  # List the shared/ namespace only if there are visible shared mailboxes.
  #list = children
#}
# Should shared INBOX be visible as "shared/user" or "shared/user/INBOX"?
#mail_shared_explicit_inbox = no

# System user and group used to access mails. If you use multiple, userdb
# can override these by returning uid or gid fields. You can use either numbers
# or names. <doc/wiki/UserIds.txt>
#mail_uid =
#mail_gid =

# Group to enable temporarily for privileged operations. Currently this is
# used only with INBOX when either its initial creation or dotlocking fails.
# Typically this is set to "mail" to give access to /var/mail.
#mail_privileged_group =
# Grant access to these supplementary groups for mail processes. Typically
# these are used to set up access to shared mailboxes. Note that it may be
# dangerous to set these if users can create symlinks (e.g. if "mail" group is
# set here, ln -s /var/mail ~/mail/var could allow a user to delete others'
# mailboxes, or ln -s /secret/shared/box ~/mail/mybox would allow reading it).
#mail_access_groups =

# Allow full filesystem access to clients. There's no access checks other than
# what the operating system does for the active UID/GID. It works with both
# maildir and mboxes, allowing you to prefix mailboxes names with eg. /path/
# or ~user/.
#mail_full_filesystem_access = no

# Dictionary for key=value mailbox attributes. Currently used by URLAUTH, but
# soon intended to be used by METADATA as well.
#mail_attribute_dict =

##
## Mail processes
##

# Don't use mmap() at all. This is required if you store indexes to shared
# filesystems (NFS or clustered filesystem).
#mmap_disable = no

# Rely on O_EXCL to work when creating dotlock files. NFS supports O_EXCL
# since version 3, so this should be safe to use nowadays by default.
#dotlock_use_excl = yes

# When to use fsync() or fdatasync() calls:
#   optimized (default): Whenever necessary to avoid losing important data
#   always: Useful with e.g. NFS when write()s are delayed
#   never: Never use it (best performance, but crashes can lose data)
#mail_fsync = optimized

# Mail storage exists in NFS. Set this to yes to make Dovecot flush NFS caches
# whenever needed. If you're using only a single mail server this isn't needed.
#mail_nfs_storage = no
# Mail index files also exist in NFS. Setting this to yes requires
# mmap_disable=yes and fsync_disable=no.
#mail_nfs_index = no

# Locking method for index files. Alternatives are fcntl, flock and dotlock.
# Dotlocking uses some tricks which may create more disk I/O than other locking
# methods. NFS users: flock doesn't work, remember to change mmap_disable.
#lock_method = fcntl

# Directory in which LDA/LMTP temporarily stores incoming mails >128 kB.
#mail_temp_dir = /tmp

# Valid UID range for users, defaults to 500 and above. This is mostly
# to make sure that users can't log in as daemons or other system users.
# Note that denying root logins is hardcoded to dovecot binary and can't
# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
#first_valid_uid = 500
#last_valid_uid = 0
# Valid GID range for users, defaults to non-root/wheel. Users having
# non-valid GID as primary group ID aren't allowed to log in. If user
# belongs to supplementary groups with non-valid GIDs, those groups are
# not set.
#first_valid_gid = 1
#last_valid_gid = 0

# Maximum allowed length for mail keyword name. It's only forced when trying
# to create new keywords.
#mail_max_keyword_length = 50

# ':' separated list of directories under which chrooting is allowed for mail
# processes (ie. /var/mail will allow chrooting to /var/mail/foo/bar too).
# This setting doesn't affect login_chroot, mail_chroot or auth chroot
# settings. If this setting is empty, "/./" in home dirs are ignored.
# WARNING: Never add directories here which local users can modify, that
# may lead to root exploit. Usually this should be done only if you don't
# allow shell access for users. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#valid_chroot_dirs =

# Default chroot directory for mail processes. This can be overridden for
# specific users in user database by giving /./ in user's home directory
# (eg. /home/./user chroots into /home). Note that usually there is no real
# need to do chrooting, Dovecot doesn't allow users to access files outside
# their mail directory anyway. If your home directories are prefixed with
# the chroot directory, append "/." to mail_chroot. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#mail_chroot =

# UNIX socket path to master authentication server to find users.
# This is used by imap (for shared users) and lda.
#auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb

# Directory where to look up mail plugins.
#mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules

# Space separated list of plugins to load for all services. Plugins specific to
# IMAP, LDA, etc. are added to this list in their own .conf files.
#mail_plugins =

##
## Mailbox handling optimizations
##

# Mailbox list indexes can be used to optimize IMAP STATUS commands. They are
# also required for IMAP NOTIFY extension to be enabled.
#mailbox_list_index = no

# The minimum number of mails in a mailbox before updates are done to cache
# file. This allows optimizing Dovecot's behavior to do less disk writes at
# the cost of more disk reads.
#mail_cache_min_mail_count = 0

# When IDLE command is running, mailbox is checked once in a while to see if
# there are any new mails or other changes. This setting defines the minimum
# time to wait between those checks. Dovecot can also use dnotify, inotify and
# kqueue to find out immediately when changes occur.

#mailbox_idle_check_interval = 30 secs

# Save mails with CR+LF instead of plain LF. This makes sending those mails
# take less CPU, especially with sendfile() syscall with Linux and FreeBSD.
# But it also creates a bit more disk I/O which may just make it slower.
# Also note that if other software reads the mboxes/maildirs, they may handle
# the extra CRs wrong and cause problems.
#mail_save_crlf = no

# Max number of mails to keep open and prefetch to memory. This only works with
# some mailbox formats and/or operating systems.
#mail_prefetch_count = 0

# How often to scan for stale temporary files and delete them (0 = never).
# These should exist only after Dovecot dies in the middle of saving mails.
#mail_temp_scan_interval = 1w

##
## Maildir-specific settings
##

# By default LIST command returns all entries in maildir beginning with a dot.
# Enabling this option makes Dovecot return only entries which are directories.
# This is done by stat()ing each entry, so it causes more disk I/O.
# (For systems setting struct dirent->d_type, this check is free and it's
# done always regardless of this setting)
#maildir_stat_dirs = no

# When copying a message, do it with hard links whenever possible. This makes
# the performance much better, and it's unlikely to have any side effects.
#maildir_copy_with_hardlinks = yes

# Assume Dovecot is the only MUA accessing Maildir: Scan cur/ directory only
# when its mtime changes unexpectedly or when we can't find the mail otherwise.
#maildir_very_dirty_syncs = no

# If enabled, Dovecot doesn't use the S=<size> in the Maildir filenames for
# getting the mail's physical size, except when recalculating Maildir++ quota.

# This can be useful in systems where a lot of the Maildir filenames have a
# broken size. The performance hit for enabling this is very small.
#maildir_broken_filename_sizes = no

##
## mbox-specific settings
##

# Which locking methods to use for locking mbox. There are four available:
#  dotlock: Create <mailbox>.lock file. This is the oldest and most NFS-safe
#           solution. If you want to use /var/mail/ like directory, the users
#           will need write access to that directory.
#  dotlock_try: Same as dotlock, but if it fails because of permissions or
#               because there isn't enough disk space, just skip it.
#  fcntl  : Use this if possible. Works with NFS too if lockd is used.
#  flock  : May not exist in all systems. Doesn't work with NFS.
#  lockf  : May not exist in all systems. Doesn't work with NFS.
#
# You can use multiple locking methods; if you do the order they're declared
# in is important to avoid deadlocks if other MTAs/MUAs are using multiple
# locking methods as well. Some operating systems don't allow using some of
# them simultaneously.
#
# The Debian value for mbox_write_locks differs from upstream Dovecot. It is
# changed to be compliant with Debian Policy (section 11.6) for NFS safety.
#       Dovecot: mbox_write_locks = dotlock fcntl
#       Debian:  mbox_write_locks = fcntl dotlock
#
#mbox_read_locks = fcntl
#mbox_write_locks = fcntl dotlock

# Maximum time to wait for lock (all of them) before aborting.
#mbox_lock_timeout = 5 mins

# If dotlock exists but the mailbox isn't modified in any way, override the
# lock file after this much time.
#mbox_dotlock_change_timeout = 2 mins
# When mbox changes unexpectedly we have to fully read it to find out what
# changed. If the mbox is large this can take a long time. Since the change
# is usually just a newly appended mail, it'd be faster to simply read the
# new mails. If this setting is enabled, Dovecot does this but still safely
# fallbacks to re-reading the whole mbox file whenever something in mbox isn't
# how it's expected to be. The only real downside to this setting is that if
# some other MUA changes message flags, Dovecot doesn't notice it immediately.
# Note that a full sync is done with SELECT, EXAMINE, EXPUNGE and CHECK
# commands.
#mbox_dirty_syncs = yes

# Like mbox_dirty_syncs, but don't do full syncs even with SELECT, EXAMINE,
# EXPUNGE or CHECK commands. If this is set, mbox_dirty_syncs is ignored.
#mbox_very_dirty_syncs = no

# Delay writing mbox headers until doing a full write sync (EXPUNGE and CHECK
# commands and when closing the mailbox). This is especially useful for POP3
# where clients often delete all mails. The downside is that our changes
# aren't immediately visible to other MUAs.
#mbox_lazy_writes = yes

# If mbox size is smaller than this (e.g. 100k), don't write index files.
# If an index file already exists it's still read, just not updated.
#mbox_min_index_size = 0

# Mail header selection algorithm to use for MD5 POP3 UIDLs when
# pop3_uidl_format=%m. For backwards compatibility we use apop3d inspired
# algorithm, but it fails if the first Received: header isn't unique in all
# mails. An alternative algorithm is "all" that selects all headers.
#mbox_md5 = apop3d

##
## mdbox-specific settings
##

# Maximum dbox file size until it's rotated.
#mdbox_rotate_size = 2M
# Maximum dbox file age until it's rotated. Typically in days. Day begins
# from midnight, so 1d = today, 2d = yesterday, etc. 0 = check disabled.
#mdbox_rotate_interval = 0

# When creating new mdbox files, immediately preallocate their size to
# mdbox_rotate_size. This setting currently works only in Linux with some
# filesystems (ext4, xfs).
#mdbox_preallocate_space = no

##
## Mail attachments
##

# sdbox and mdbox support saving mail attachments to external files, which
# also allows single instance storage for them. Other backends don't support
# this for now.

# Directory root where to store mail attachments. Disabled, if empty.
#mail_attachment_dir =
# Attachments smaller than this aren't saved externally. It's also possible to
# write a plugin to disable saving specific attachments externally.
#mail_attachment_min_size = 128k

# Filesystem backend to use for saving attachments:
#  posix : No SiS done by Dovecot (but this might help FS's own deduplication)
#  sis posix : SiS with immediate byte-by-byte comparison during saving
#  sis-queue posix : SiS with delayed comparison and deduplication
#mail_attachment_fs = sis posix

# Hash format to use in attachment filenames. You can add any text and
# variables: %{md4}, %{md5}, %{sha1}, %{sha256}, %{sha512}, %{size}.
# Variables can be truncated, e.g. %{sha256:80} returns only first 80 bits
#mail_attachment_hash = %{sha1}
```

Heres a image of how my DNS is setup. Think it should be correct:

[image: DNS image]

I use squirrelmail to display as webmail. 
Only thing I've changed in its setup is the corporation name as mentioned in the guide I followed.

I found this in the log, which is what happens when I send a email from my gmail to my mailserver. I'm not quite sure how to interpret it. It seemed as I had followed another guide using virtual alias it redirects the email. Not sure though. Found the old `/etc/postfix/virtual` file and removed the alias posted in it. saved it and updated postmap and restarted the service. But same error in log.

I think the problem lies here, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Feb 18 12:45:14 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[24925]: connect from mail-ig0-f174.google.com[209.85.213.174]
Feb 18 12:45:14 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[24925]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ig0-f174.google.com[209.85.213.174]: TLSv1.2 wi$
Feb 18 12:45:14 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[24925]: E9887268310F: client=mail-ig0-f174.google.com[209.85.213.174]
Feb 18 12:45:15 vps141712 postfix/cleanup[24931]: E9887268310F: message-id=<CA+amF8io8PeYJDtNpORE1ASA8voBVbevjBnT50Xt59SGtNrozg@mail.gmail.com>
Feb 18 12:45:15 vps141712 postfix/qmgr[24852]: E9887268310F: from=<mazurandersen@gmail.com>, size=2323, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 18 12:45:15 vps141712 postfix/local[24932]: E9887268310F: to=<root@stahp.ovh>, orig_to=<postmaster@stahp.ovh>, relay=local, delay=0.3, del$
Feb 18 12:45:15 vps141712 postfix/qmgr[24852]: E9887268310F: removed
Feb 18 12:45:15 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[24925]: disconnect from mail-ig0-f174.google.com[209.85.213.174]
```

`mail.log`:

```
Feb 18 09:25:05 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23389]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ob0-f182.google.com[209.85.214.182]: TLSv1.2 wit$
Feb 18 09:25:06 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23389]: 355E42683111: client=mail-ob0-f182.google.com[209.85.214.182]
Feb 18 09:25:06 vps141712 postfix/cleanup[23395]: 355E42683111: message-id=<CAC3Pkvt10n3DRexS00XSySNnDtTqjGE_c872JMrHn1QyngPtUw@mail.gmail.com>
Feb 18 09:25:06 vps141712 postfix/qmgr[23317]: 355E42683111: from=<williamstrand8@gmail.com>, size=3548, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 18 09:25:06 vps141712 postfix/local[23396]: 355E42683111: to=<root@stahp.ovh>, orig_to=<postmaster@stahp.ovh>, relay=local, delay=0.29, del$
Feb 18 09:25:06 vps141712 postfix/qmgr[23317]: 355E42683111: removed
Feb 18 09:25:06 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23389]: disconnect from mail-ob0-f182.google.com[209.85.214.182]
Feb 18 09:25:16 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23399, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:16 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1535
Feb 18 09:25:16 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23401, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:16 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=85 out=771
Feb 18 09:25:23 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23406, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:23 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=44 out=831
Feb 18 09:25:23 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23408, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:23 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=285 out=1659
Feb 18 09:25:23 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23410, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:23 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1535
Feb 18 09:25:25 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23412, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:25 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=85 out=771

Feb 18 09:25:26 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23414, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:26 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1535
Feb 18 09:25:27 vps141712 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=23416, secured, sessi$
Feb 18 09:25:27 vps141712 dovecot: imap(postmaster): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1535
Feb 18 09:28:26 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23392]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.214.182) at Feb 18 09:25:05
Feb 18 09:28:26 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23392]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.214.182) at Feb 18 09:25:05
Feb 18 09:28:26 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23392]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 18 09:25:05
Feb 18 09:30:41 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23429]: connect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 09:30:41 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23429]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 09:30:41 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23429]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 09:34:01 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23431]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 09:30:41
Feb 18 09:34:01 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23431]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 09:30:41
Feb 18 09:34:01 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23431]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 18 09:30:41
Feb 18 10:00:40 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23491]: connect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 10:00:40 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23491]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 10:00:40 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23491]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 10:04:01 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23493]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 10:00:40
Feb 18 10:04:01 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23493]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 10:00:40
Feb 18 10:04:01 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23493]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 18 10:00:40

Feb 18 10:30:46 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23547]: connect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 10:30:46 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23547]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 10:30:46 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23547]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 10:34:06 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23549]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 10:30:46
Feb 18 10:34:06 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23549]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 10:30:46
Feb 18 10:34:06 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23549]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 18 10:30:46
Feb 18 11:00:47 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23606]: connect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 11:00:47 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23606]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 11:00:47 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23606]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 11:04:07 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23610]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 11:00:47
Feb 18 11:04:07 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23610]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 11:00:47
Feb 18 11:04:07 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23610]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 18 11:00:47
Feb 18 11:30:43 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23664]: connect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 11:30:44 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23664]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 11:30:44 vps141712 postfix/smtpd[23664]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
Feb 18 11:34:04 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23666]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 11:30:43
Feb 18 11:34:04 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23666]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 18 11:30:43
Feb 18 11:34:04 vps141712 postfix/anvil[23666]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 18 11:30:43
```

Comment: Is there anything in the log? /var/log/mail.log

Comment: Added the log that probably describes the error

Comment: Unless you have aliases set up in Dovecot for `root` and `postmaster`, you'll never see email show up for non-user accounts. `root` and `postmaster`, while valid users, are typically blocked out in Postfix other than for internal (`localhost`) emails. Do you have another user mailbox set up that you can try sending email to?

Comment: Ehh. It's on a VPS and my only access is ssh to `root`. So Root account is the only user mailbox I could set up?
So if I want emails to `postmaster` to go though to me, I would need to set up aliases? (don't have a clue about how to configure that atm.)

I did use `sudo useradd -m postmaster -s /sbin/nologin` to add the  `postmaster`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586856/postfix-dovecot-mail-server-can-send-mails-but-not-recive/587094#comment813964_586856), Douggro.

> Unless you have aliases set up in Dovecot for root and postmaster, you'll never see email show up for non-user accounts. root and postmaster, while valid users, are typically blocked out in Postfix other than for internal (localhost) emails

It led me on the right track to solve the issue.

I added a new user and used alias to route all mails to root to that user.

I now recieve the emails :D

Comment: No worries about rep points. Just glad that I got you thinking in a direction that led to a solution.